# How to display images in elements created with javascript using an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image

I'm new to JavaScript, so apologies if any of my terminology is wrong or confusing - I'm still trying to learn!
I'm trying to create a page that adds the image from an array to a div that's created on page load. At best I can get it to show the path of the image, but I can't get it to show the actual image. This is the code I've got so far (in this, nothing at all is showing in the element, not even the path)

HTML:

```
<main>
   <div id="style-container">
   </div>
</main>
```

JavaScript:

```
const styles = [
    {
      description: 'Alunar Gold Leather Sling Back Heels',
      code: 'ALUNAR GDL',
      img: 'static/images/ALUNAR-GDL.jpg'
    },
    {
      description: 'Alunar Green Leather Sling Back Heels',
      code: 'ALUNAR GNL',
      img: 'static/images/ALUNAR-GNL.jpg'
    },
    {
      description: 'Alunar Silver Leather Sling Back Heels',
      code: 'ALUNAR SLL',
      img: 'static/images/ALUNAR-SLL.jpg'
    },
    {
      description: 'Alunar White Leather Sling Back Heels',
      code: 'ALUNAR WTL',
      img: 'static/images/ALUNAR-WTL.jpg'
    },
]

const createStyle = () => {
    let i;
    for (i = 0; i < styles.length; i++) {
        const styleDiv = document.createElement('div');
        styleDiv.setAttribute('class', 'style');
        const getStyleContainer = document.getElementById('style-container');
        getStyleContainer.appendChild(styleDiv);
        styleDiv.style.width = ('100px');
        styleDiv.style.height = ('200px');
        styleDiv.style.margin = ('20px');
        styleDiv.style.display = ('flex');
        styleDiv.style.justifyContent = ('center');
        styleDiv.style.alignItems = ('center');
        const styleImage = document.createElement('img');
        styleDiv.appendChild(styleImage);
        styleImage.innerHTML = styles[i].img;
        styleImage.style.width = ('100px');
        styleImage.style.height = ('200px');
        styleImage.style.objectFit = ('contain');
    }
}

window.onload = () => {
    createStyle();
}
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated

Thanks

Comment: you should be setting the `src` of the image, not the `innerHTML`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

InnerHtml property sets or returns the HTML content (inner HTML) of an element. For image use src to set the path

```
styleImage.innerHTML = styles[i].img; to styleImage.src= styles[i].img;
```

Answer (score 0):

- you were missing to set `src` attribute of `img` tag.
- I have used `forEach` loop to loop through `styles` array of object, As it's just more readable formated
- Below function `createElemt()` return element with classname and tag given in function parameter.

```js
function createElem(tagName, className) {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName);
  element.setAttribute('class', className);
  return element;
}
```

- I have defined all the `css` from javascript to `css` as it's easy.

```js
const styles = [{
    description: 'Alunar Gold Leather Sling Back Heels',
    code: 'ALUNAR GDL',
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=1&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%201x,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=2&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%202x'
  },
  {
    description: 'Alunar Green Leather Sling Back Heels',
    code: 'ALUNAR GNL',
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=1&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%201x,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=2&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%202x'
  },
  {
    description: 'Alunar Silver Leather Sling Back Heels',
    code: 'ALUNAR SLL',
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=1&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%201x,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=2&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%202x'
  },
  {
    description: 'Alunar White Leather Sling Back Heels',
    code: 'ALUNAR WTL',
    img: 'https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=1&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%201x,%20https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1656231869720-da7f20280b5f?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxwaG90by1vZi10aGUtZGF5fHx8fGVufDB8fHx8&dpr=2&auto=format%2Ccompress&fit=crop&w=1999&h=594%202x'
  },
]

const createStyle = () => {
  styles.forEach(style => {
    const styleDiv = createElem("div", "style"); // calling createElem function
    const getStyleContainer = document.getElementById('style-container');
    getStyleContainer.appendChild(styleDiv);
    const styleImage = createElem("img", "myImg-style"); // calling createElem function
    styleImage.src = style.img; // you were missing this it says that set src attribute to style.img(I have used unsplash images) for your code it's your path
    styleDiv.appendChild(styleImage);
    const myTitle = createElem("h1", "my-title");
    myTitle.innerHTML = style.code;
    styleDiv.appendChild(myTitle);
    const myDescription = createElem("p", "my-description");
    myDescription.innerHTML = style.description;
    styleDiv.appendChild(myDescription);
  })
}
// for creating an elemnt
function createElem(tagName, className) {
  const element = document.createElement(tagName);
  element.setAttribute('class', className);
  return element;
}
window.onload = () => {
  createStyle();
}
```

```css
// to reduce styling by javascript
.style {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 20px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.myImg-style {
  width: 100px;
  height: 200px;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <div id="style-container">
  </div>
</main>
```

Comment: Hey, thanks, this is great, the code separation is really useful

Comment: Welcome:) dunction is always great